# How to store current URL of the page in a variable for validation purpose on TestComplete

Tags: testcomplete

I am working on testcomplete automation tool. I want to know how can I store current URL in a variable for validation. Example,

I click a link that takes me to a particular page. I want to validate against the URL of that page. how can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the URL property of the Page object. Information on this property along with a script sample can be found in this document:
[URL Property (Page Objects)](http://smartbear.com/viewarticle/74531/)

Answer (score 0):

If it's not opening in a tab/window then this should work fine:

```
function PageSample()
{

  Browsers.Item(btIExplorer).Run("http://smartbear.com/");

  // Obtains the browser process
  var browser = Sys.Browser("iexplore");
  // Obtains the page currently opened in Internet Explorer
  var page = browser.Page("*");
  // Use the page object property and add a checkpoint to validate

  …

}
```